# Como contar o número de seguidores do twitter via php?

Tags: php, twitter-api

Bom dia. Estou desenvolvendo um blog e preciso listar o número de seguidores que certa empresa tem, mas não estou conseguindo fazer. Consegui fazer a listagem de curtidas do facebook mas do twitter não consigo de jeito nenhum

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=cissamagazine'); if (preg_match('/followers_count>(.*)</', $xml, $array) != 0) {
$seguidores['count'] = $array[1];}echo $seguidores['count'];
```

Comment: poste um pedaço de código, algum resultado de testes que voce fez...

Comment: essa foi a minha última tentativa

$xml = file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=cissamagazine');
if (preg_match('/followers_count>(.*)</', $xml, $array) != 0) {
    $seguidores['count'] = $array[1];
}
echo $seguidores['count'];

Comment: @GabrielSchmidtCordeiro adicione este código na pergunta e não apenas nos comentários ;)

Comment: Não rola usar a API do Twitter ao invés de fazer scraping da página?

Comment: @GabrielSchmidtCordeiro isso não te ajuda? http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/2009/10/19/mostrar-numero-de-seguidores-do-twitter-no-blog/

Comment: @GWER vou verificar

Comment: @LuisCipriani vou ver o que consigo fazer. Mas acho que deve existir algo mais fácil se for comparado com o que fiz para pegar o número de curtidas do facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pela API do Twitter

Já faz um tempo que o **Twitter** fechou bastante o acesso às informações e até limitado requisições para a comunidade de desenvolvedores. Você pode verificar que nas [REST APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) da versão **1.1** (que é a atual) é necessário autenticação para realizar qualquer tipo de requisição, inclusive para esta que você tentou fazer, a [`GET users/show`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show).

Eu tenho um [post](http://www.riabox.com.br/blog/php-obtendo-informacoes-do-twitter-utilizando-a-api-1-1/) detalhado no meu site sobre isso. Mas basicamente os passos para chegar ao seu objetivo através do método [Application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) são estes:

- [Criar uma aplicação](https://apps.twitter.com/) para obter **API key** e **API secret**;
- Através das chaves, obter o **bearer token**;
- Com o *token*, realizar a requisição desejada;

Obtendo o *bearer token*:

```
$encoded_consumer_key = urlencode(CONSUMER_KEY); // API key
$encoded_consumer_secret = urlencode(CONSUMER_SECRET); // API secret
$bearer_token = $encoded_consumer_key . ':' . $encoded_consumer_secret;
$base64_consumer_key = base64_encode($bearer_token);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
$headers = array(
        "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1",
        "Host: api.twitter.com",
        "User-Agent: Twitter Application-only OAuth App",
        "Authorization: Basic " . $base64_consumer_key,
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Length: 29"
);
 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
$header = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$output = explode("\n", $response);
$bearer_token = '';
foreach($output as $line) {
    if ($line !== false) {
        $bearer_token = $line;
    }
}
$bearer_token = json_decode($bearer_token);
$bearer_token = $bearer_token->{'access_token'};
```

Quando então você tem o *token* em mãos, você pode fazer sua requisição para obter as informações do usuário:

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json";
$formed_url = '?screen_name=cissamagazine';
$headers = array(
        "GET /1.1/users/show.json" . $formed_url . " HTTP/1.1",
        "Host: api.twitter.com",
        "User-Agent: Twitter Application-only OAuth App",
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $bearer_token,
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $formed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Na variável `$response` você terá um `JSON`, que você pode manipulá-la da forma que deseja para obter as informações do usuário.

Comment: Paulo, sou desenvolvedor evangelista do Twitter aqui no Brasil. Por favor, se puder me informar que tipo de limitação você teve com a API nós podemos ajudar. A informação dos números de seguidores é pública, não há porque limitar e está disponível em qualquer representação que retorne a entidade do usuário, assim como você mostra na sua resposta.

Comment: Luis, talvez me expressei de forma errada. O que eu quis dizer com "limitado" é referente ao limite de requisições que podem ser feitas por um determinado período de tempo, assim como mostra na documentação que eu citei em minha resposta.

Comment: Sim, o rate limit realmente existe para evitar abusos, mas conseguimos flexibilizar os limites para parceiros dependendo da necessidade. É só dar um toque via @TwitterDevBr. Abs